# Email Newsletter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a newsletter. Newsletter content is saved in the table along with frequency such monthly, weekly, daily. Newsletter also have start date. What I have to do is based on the data and frequency. Newsletters are emailed to all the subscribers. My confusion is that whether I need to write a sql server job for this or simply asp.net can do this. If yes then how would I be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually went for the application events. I set the timer in application event and it works similar like jobs and windows services.

Answer (score 1):

As your web application will be terminated in times of inactivity, you usually have a service or task scheduler run such periodical tasks. Also your web application is responsible to return requests quickly and should run with a very limited set of permissions that might not be enough for your jobs (it is preferable not to allow the app pool account to send e-mails to lots of accounts).
There are various alternatives that differ in terms of convenience  and deployment of your application. 

An important requirement besides the capability to run jobs periodically is how you can trace errors in the job, so you should think about your logging strategy before the first problems arise.

Besides writing a SQL Server job, you could also:

- Create a console application and use Windows task scheduler to run it periodically (interval is the minimum of your scheduling options, in your question daily). This is easy to implement, but requires some steps to deploy it to a computer.
- Create a dedicated windows service that is installed to the computer. While this requires more effort to create and test the service, you can also create an installer to simplify the deployment.